# Updating Entity in EF6 gives primary key exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

When I try to update this object in EF6 I get an error stating more than 1 entity has this primary key. Looking at this DB I know this to be untrue(from what I can see).

I need to be able to update a second object based on one of the properties on the posted object. The code below produces the error. I have left in commented out pieces that I have tried to get this to work.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(PricingRule pricingRule)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var currentUser = await serv.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var company = currentUser.Company;
            //var entityRule = serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Get(pricingRule.PricingRuleId);


            //If this is the first rule, set it to the company default
            var rulesCount = company.PricingRules.Count;
            if (rulesCount <= 1 || company.DefaultPricingRule == null)
                pricingRule.DefaultPricingRule = true;


            //Make sure no other rules are marked as default, and update the company with this rule as default
            if (pricingRule.DefaultPricingRule)
            {
                if (company.DefaultPricingRule != null)
                {
                    var oldRule = serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Get(company.DefaultPricingRule.PricingRuleId);
                    oldRule.DefaultPricingRule = false;
                    //serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Update(oldRule);
                }
                company.DefaultPricingRule = pricingRule;
                serv.CoreService.Companies.Update(company);

            }

            serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Update(pricingRule);
            await serv.SaveAllChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pricingRule);
    }
```

Comment: It's very difficult to tell without seeing your model, your EF mappings, the operations you do with the contexts and without knowing what is the PK that EF complains about. Are you mixing operations from 2 DbContexts (IdentityDbContext and your own)? That's a wild guess, but maybe the problem is that you are attaching the company object from the identity context to your own every time?

Comment: I will update my question once I get home but wanted to comment and say that I have solved the issue. The issue was that I needed to set the pricing rule object to modified before operating on the other objects. Without doing this it was trying to add/update a new object? Even though it existed already. I am operating only on one context at all times. The serv variable is declared controller wide and uses one context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not it is the best practice or how it should technically be done, this is how I solved my problem.

The edited object I was passing in, needed to be marked as modified first, before doing any other operations. I am assuming this is because the context could then grab it and all other operations regarding it would be done "within context". Other wise I think it was trying to add a new object if I tried to attach it to company.DefaultPricingRule.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(PricingRule pricingRule)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Update(pricingRule);
            var currentUser = await serv.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            var company = currentUser.Company;

            //If this is the first rule, set it to the company default
            var rulesCount = company.PricingRules.Count;
            if (rulesCount <= 1 || company.DefaultPricingRule == null)
                pricingRule.DefaultPricingRule = true;


            //Make sure no other rules are marked as default, and update the company with this rule as default
            if (pricingRule.DefaultPricingRule)
            {
                if (company.DefaultPricingRule != null)
                {
                    var oldRule = serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Get(company.DefaultPricingRule.PricingRuleId);
                    oldRule.DefaultPricingRule = false;
                    serv.PricingService.PricingRules.Update(oldRule);
                }

                company.DefaultPricingRule = pricingRule;
                serv.CoreService.Companies.Update(company);
            }

            await serv.SaveAllChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(pricingRule);
    }
```

If Anyone has a comment on if this is best practice or if there is a better way to do it, I gladly take criticism.

Comment: Good to know you have it working. More than mark it as modified, what makes a difference is that the object is attached to the context (and marked unchanged). Then if the object is modified, EF will detect it. For the same reason, I don't think you need the calls to Update(oldRule) and Update(company). Both objects should already be attached and EF will issue update statements for them.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I left those in because it was working, but wasnt sure if I needed them. I still was unsure exactly what attach did even after reading about it. If I "attach" it, does it find the matching entity in the db? or will it try to create a new object?

Comment: Atttaching an object won't load it from the db nor create it. EF will basically "know" about that object, it will make a snapshot of it, and consider it unchanged. If you change properties, when you call Save, EF will see that the object has been modify it and update it. At this point, the object must exist in the DB otherwise you'll get an exception. To create the object you need to Add it. You can also force a modification, creation or deletion by manually changing the object state: context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;